# mapping object query in hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I work with Spring boot version 2 and I use JPA and  hibernate version 5.2.

I have a native query with return some data and array data which represent an object .

```
select  id as id,name as name,ARRAY[id,name] as children
    from book .......
     ........
  Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "BookDTOMap");

     List<BookDTO> bookDTOs = query.getResultList();
```

BookDTO.java

```
public class BookDTO  {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String[] children;

  public BookDTO(String id, String name, String[] children) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children;
  }
}
```

Book.java have this kind of code :

```
 @SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "BookDTOMap",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
      targetClass = BookDTO.class,
      columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "id"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
        @ColumnResult(name = "children")
    )
  )
```

when I test I have this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve column name in result set [children]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name children was not found in this ResultSet.
```

I try to change BookDTO without success:

```
public class BookDTO  {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private BookDTO[] children;

  public BookDTO(String id, String name, BookDTO[] children) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children;
  }
}
```

this is the error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve column name in result set [children]
...................
..................
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
```

can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Children is a collection right - so it's gonna have a different annotation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: thanks for your response, I try with this code also without success ; private Collection<BookDTO>  children;      ,the result of column children in query  is like this :  "{B-1,"test1",B2,"test2"}"

Comment: What PostgreSQL version, hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL  vesion 11 and jpa hibernate spring boot,
I use Native Query for some complex query and Spring data for other

like this
public class BookRepositoryCustomImpl implements BookRepositoryCustom {

  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;
  public List<BookDTO> findTreeBook() {
  
  String querystr = " with recursive nodes as  ";
  querystr += " select  id as id,name as name,ARRAY[id,name] as children ";
  querystr += "  ....... ";
  Query query = em.createNativeQuery(querystr, "BookDTOMap");

     List<BookDTO> bookDTOs = query.getResultList();